# Fit More Widgets on Wordpress Footer

Tags: css, wordpress, widget, footer, areas

My theme shows that I can fit up to 4 widgets in the footer as shown in the demo site here:
http://demo.woothemes.com/?name=simplicity

But I can only fit 2 on mine when I'd like to have 3. Here's my site for my assignment:
http://www.brightpixelstudios.com/

I'm guessing I'll need to modify the CSS. I'd really appreciate any suggestions!

Thank you in advance,

Will

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, if you look at the output, yours says:

```
<div id="footer-widgets" class="col-full col-2">
```

But changing the output to:

```
<div id="footer-widgets" class="col-full col-4">
```

Divides the width into 4 parts.

I can't help much more without seeing the actual admin side of the website, but if the `col-4` is set dynamically, then it'd be a setting you'd have to change for the theme in the admin side.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions, they really helped me understand the structure of the footer more. But as it turns out, the amount of widgets shown in the footer is controlled under Dashboard>Theme Options. Silly me!

Comment: @WillWhitehead Yes I thought it would be in the admin side, glad it helped anyway!

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'BNS Add Widget' wordpress plug in to add a widget area to the footer of any wordpress theme.

This is the plug in link : http://buynowshop.com/plugins/bns-add-widget/